# Visual Studio and Silverlight deployment

Tags: silverlight, deployment

I am using the Publish functionality to deploy my Silverlight webapplication. I am not hosting it in an aspx page, just a plain html page. I do not need all the extra aps.net stuff. When I publish it, it wants to add a bin folder, and it wants to compile the site it seems. Is there any way I can disable this? I just want my index.html file together with some xml files copied to the ftp server of my hosting provider.